# Uploading files using the Postman binary method to wso2 esb cannot receive files?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

This error message comes while uploading files

```
INFO - LogMediator To: /services/file, MessageID: urn:uuid:3fcb9ae1-bd3e-45d9-8ece-ac5658a51acb, Direction: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error while building message, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><xformValues/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```